# How to remotely control iPhone 6 which dropped and right side screen is not working

Tags: iphone, screen, remote-control, damage

I dropped my iPhone 6 and the right side of the screen is black. I cannot type there, I can't activate my Wi-Fi access and data access. I need it to turn this on. Is there a way to remotely control the iPhone from my laptop?

Comment: Why don't you activate access to Wi-Fi etc. with your **laptop**?

Comment: I dont know how to do that i connected the iphone cable to the laptop it is just charging and i can only access photos

Answer (score 1):

Turn your phone sideways and use landscape mode. If you are using the software switch you won't be able to do this as it's on the right side of the screen.

If that is the case, connect the phone to iTunes, make a local backup, and take it in for servicing. Either a new screen or a new phone. When you get it back, reconnect to iTunes and restore from backup. Everything will be the same as before.